# Safari double reading an XML node when accessed by id with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, safari

I am using jQuery to read XML that is returned by an ajax call.  In only the Safari browser, I am getting a duplicate/double read of the node I am requesting.

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<record>
<f id="1">2</f>
<f id="2">er</f>
<f id="3">bd1rh24</f>
<f id="4">9</f>
<f id="5">1</f>
<f id="6">Experience Type</f>
<f id="7">Dashboard Search</f>
<f id="8">bd1rh24</f>
<f id="9">Virtual Reality</f>
<f id="10">Test</f>
</record>
```

My HTML & Javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                var url = "test.xml";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: url,
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success: function(data) {
                        $.each($("record", data), function() {
                            sCchoices = $("f[id='9']", this).text();
                            alert(sCchoices);
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

In all browsers (IE, Chrome, FireFox), except Safari, the alert outputs "Test".  In Safari the output is "TestTest".  I have figured out that the issue is that the number of node is equal to the id number that I am entering.  10 nodes - id=10.  If you request another node id then the output is correct and does not duplicate.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: wait... shouldn't the output be `Virtual Reality`? http://jsfiddle.net/gUUFS/ (performs identically in chrome vs safari for me)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake in the code above.  Try $("f[id=10]", this).text(); http://jsfiddle.net/gUUFS/1/